# How to create a subversion repository from local working copy and keep logs and history?

Tags: git, svn, server, local, relocation

I have a local working copy of a subversion repository. The server for this project does not exist anymore but I would like to use the working copy I have to create a new local repository that keeps logs and history of the project if possible.

I tried lot of things, spent several days trying to do this but could not figure it out.
As I had issues with relocate and file:/// protocol, I tried to use svnserve and create a windows service. But It seems my folder does not have the good structure. I have only a .svn folder in my repo but the informations I found tells I should have conf, db, hooks folders etc...
As a result my folder is not recognized as a svn repo.

Is it possible to do this and what would be the proper way.

My initial goal was to convert the project to Git, but as I failed to convert it, I tried first to make it a working subversion repo. To convert it later once it works.

I read lot of posts, but most explain how to do with a working repo on a server. In my case I just have an old working copy and the server that was not maintained by myself has been shutdown.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logs and history are only located on the server and requested everytime when one wants to see them.

As there is no server any more (and no copy of the repository) it is imposible to create a new repository using an old checkout. - Git is different as a clone is a full copy of the repository (logs, history and all other actions are local except for push and pull).

However, it is, of course, possible to create a new subversion repository and use the old data as an initial commit.